# Populating variable with JSON response from backend

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a bit clueless with javascript, so would appreciate pointers with what's (not) happening here.

The following snippet is supposed to populate the `data` variable with the response (JSON) from a PHP backend.  The `response` variable indeed contains the data (I confirmed with Firebug and a breakpoint):

`[Object { identifier=0, value="clothing made in the us"}, Object { identifier=1, value="club penguin trading cards"}, Object { identifier=2, value="cobra quad bikes"}, 22 more...]`

However, by the time the `return data;` line is reached, `data` contains nothing.

```
var data = [];
new response.each(function(identifier, item){
    this.include({value: identifier, text: item.text});
}, data);
return data;
```

I'm having difficulty mapping my knowledge of (eg) Perl's foreach loop with what's happening here.  I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Even better, how can I rewrite that .each() loop to be more readable?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
var data = [];
response.each(function(obj) {
         this.include({identifier: obj.id, value: obj.descr});
}, data);
return data;
```

I'll eventually get this JS.